# Pegar dados de uma linha selecionada de uma table dinâmica

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho uma tabela, que eu incluo os dados dinamicamente em uma table. 
Incluo desta forma, eu incluo na primeira coluna os checkbox:

```
$("#tablepesquisaprodutos").append("<tr class='item'>"
                    + "<td>" + "<input type='checkbox' class='link-check' />" + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + CodigoProduto + "</td>"
                    + "<td>" + DescricaoProduto + "</td>"
                    + "</tr>")
```

Funciona perfeitamente, porém eu preciso que ao marcar o checkbox, eu consigo excluir ou editar a linha (abrindo um modal com os dados da linha), como posso fazer?
Excluir eu consigo por um button, eu faço dessa maneira:

```
  $(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.link-excluir', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // isso aqui impede do '#' fazer o link pular
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.closest("tr").fadeOut(500, function () {
            $el.remove();
        })
    })
})
```

Só que no caso eu tenho o link para excluir na linha, eu preciso é selecionar a linha, e depois clicar no button da ação, ou excluir ou alterar.

Comment: `$(".link-check").change();` não serve pra você? Ai dentro só verifica se está checado ou não e faz aparecer/desaparecer

Comment: Se quiser abrir uma moda, tem vários exemplos aqui no site, como esse: [como abrir modal jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11024/57220), ou esse: [editar campos em modal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220341/57220). Agora uma forma mais fácil e tornar a `TD` editável, basta mudar seu código para `+ "<td contenteditable='true'>" +` e vai ser possível editar o valor direto na `TD`, o que acha?

Comment: @MáttheusSpoo  eu queria que ao selecionar ele clicasse no button ou pra alterar ou pra excluir, acho que com o change não daria certo.

Comment: @RicardoPontual a ideia é boa, porém eu preciso q ele selecione para depois clicar no button de excluir ou de alterar

Comment: Nesse caso, você pode adicionar o atributo `contenteditable='true'` ao clicar no botão de alterar ou ao marcar o checkbox, e no evento `blur` da `TD` remover o atributo :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual mas eu não entendi como fazer isso. Eu vou selecionar o checkbox da linha que eu quero excluir ou alterar, como posso pegar o valor desta linha, e ao clicar no button de excluir, excluir, e no button de alterar, abrir a modal com os dados.

Comment: Mas você quer editar direto na tabela como eu sugeri ou quer abrir a modal?

Comment: Eu quero editar abrindo o modal. Eu já faço isso com um link em cada linha, porém em vez de ter o link, eu quero ter o checkbox, selecionar, e ai sim, eu clicar em um button de fora da table para realizar ação desejada

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu consegui excluir, agora como posso ao clicar no checkbox, e clicar no button de editar, abrir o modal com as informações da table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui excluir, jogando a linha em uma variável global, desta forma, e então ao clicar no button, eu executo a função de excluir:

```
   $(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.link-check', function (e) {
        $thatRow = $(this);
    })
})
```

E aqui a função que fica no button para excluir a linha.

```
    function ExcluirProdutoPedido(linha) {
    $thatRow.closest("tr").fadeOut(500, function () {
        $thatRow.remove();

    })
```

E aqui para pegar os valores da linha selecionada e abrir o modal com os valores:

```
 $("#idproduto").val($thatRow.closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).text());
    CarregaProduto($thatRow.closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).text());
    $("#qtd").val($thatRow.closest('tr').find('td').eq(3).text());
    $("#precocusto").val($thatRow.closest('tr').find('td').eq(4).text());
    $("#descontop").val($thatRow.closest('tr').find('td').eq(5).text());
    $("#descontov").val($thatRow.closest('tr').find('td').eq(6).text());
    $("#icms").val($thatRow.closest('tr').find('td').eq(8).text());
    $("#aliquotaicms").html($thatRow.closest('tr').find('td').eq(9).text());
    $("#ipi").val($thatRow.closest('tr').find('td').eq(13).text());
    $("#iss").val($thatRow.closest('tr').find('td').eq(11).text());
    $("#dataentrega").val($thatRow.closest('tr').find('td').eq(17).text());

    abreModalAdd();
```